# __attribute (NSObject) is for pointer type only

Tags: objective-c, properties

I am dealing with a third party library and I get the build error on the following line:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) __attribute__((NSObject)) dispatch_queue_t captureQueue;
```

The error is:

```
 __attribute ((NSObject)) is for pointer types only
```

What does it mean?

Comment: Just get rid of the `__attribute__((NSObject))` part of the property definition. You don't need it.